# Compute $\int\frac{1}{3+\cos^3{x}}\mathrm{d} x$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I have an integral which seems hard for me:
$$\int\frac{1}{3+\cos^3{x}}\,\mathrm{d}x.$$
If I use Weierstrass substitution I get $I=\int{\frac{(1+t^2)^2}{3(1+t^2)^3+(1-t^2)^3}dt} $ I was stuck here

Comment: I'd try the [Weierstrass substitution](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution), but I can't promise you it won't be very messy.

Comment: I would probably factor the denominator using complex numbers, then write the whole thing using partial fractions, and *then* use https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith  I have tried Weierstrass substitution but I didn't solve it

Comment: What integral do you end up with after the Weierstrass substitution? And what is your problem with that integral? (I admit that this one is a bit problematic, in the sense that the numbers involved will not be too nice.)

Comment: why this is off-topic?! it has a solution. Dividing the denumenator and numenator by $\cos^3 x$, we get $I=\int{\frac{\sec^3 x}{3\sec^3 x+1}dx}$. Let $u=\sec^3 x$, $du=3 u (u^{2/3}-1)^{1/2}$, we get $I=\int{\frac{du}{(3u^2+1)(u^{2/3}-1)^{1/2}}}$. Now let $u^{1/3}=t$, we get $I=\int{\frac{3t^2}{(3t^6+1)(t^2-1)^{1/2}}dt}$. Also, let $z^2=t^2-1$, we find that $I=\int{\frac{3(z^2+1)^{1/2}}{3(z^2+1)^3+1}dz}$.. you can proceed now

Comment: Another solution you can substitute $\cos x = \frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}$ with $dx=\frac{2}{t^2+1}dt$

Comment: @Dr.MohammadAlomari  if $u=\sec^3x$,$dx=-1/3            t^{-4/3}(1-t^{-2/3}^{-1/2}$ then I get $I=\int{\frac{t^{5/3}}{3(3t^3+1)(1-t^{-2/3})^{1/2}}}$ then I find it's more difficult

Comment: @mickep If I use Weierstrass substitution I get $I=\int{\frac{(1+t^2)^2}{3(1+t^2)^3+(1-t^2)^3}dt} I was stuck here

Comment: I think you should edit the question and give those details. You could also write why you cannot proceed. Then maybe the question will be opened up again (I don't know how that works).

Comment: @columbus8myhw and Robert Jiang : "Weierstrass substitution" is a misnomer.  The assertion in Stewart's calculus book that Weierstrass had something to do with this substitution is based on nothing. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I outline some steps for you to work with.

First solve
$$
t^3+3=0.
$$
Call the solutions $t_1$, $t_2$ and $t_3$ (two of them will be complex).

Next, you use the fact (partial fraction decomposition) that
$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{1}{(x-t_1)(x-t_2)(x-t_3)}&=\frac{1}{(t_1-t_2)(t_1-t_3)(x-t_1)}+\frac{1}{(t_2-t_1)(t_2-t_3)(x-t_2)}\\
&\qquad+\frac{1}{(t_3-t_1)(t_3-t_2)(x-t_3)}.
\end{aligned}
$$
You are now about to tackle three integrals of the form (forgetting constants)
$$
\int\frac{1}{\cos x-t}\,dx.
$$
Via $u=\tan(x/2)$ you will find that
$$
\int\frac{1}{\cos x-t}\,dx=\frac{2\text{arctanh}\,\Bigl(\frac{\sqrt{1+t}\tan(x/2)}{\sqrt{1-t}}\Bigr)}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}+C
$$
Of course, in the end you should be a bit careful since the constants are complex and you expect a real result, but in principle it should work out.

Answer (score 2):

Robert, observe that$\frac{1}{3+cos^2x}=\frac{sec^2x}{3sec^2x+1}=\frac{sec^2x}{4+3tan^2x}$ Now do u-sub $tanx=u$ on the integral and the result is essentially an $arctan$ No need for Weierstrass, just High School Calculus

Comment: It seems something is off with your Math Jax?

Comment: @Sky Yes, I fixed it now. Can you undo the -1 ?

Comment: I don't know how you get $\frac{\sec^2x}{3\sec^2x+1}=\frac{\sec^2x}{4+3\tan^2x}$ maybe

Comment: @RobertJiang Use identity $sec^2x=tan^2x+1$

Comment: @imranfat but it's \frac{1}{3+\cos^3x}.

Comment: @RobertJiang No, it is $3+cos^2x$ there is no cube. So $3(tan^2x+1)+1$ which becomes $4+3tan^2x$

Comment: @imranfat if there is no cube the question is too easy  So In my question there is a cube indeed

Comment: @RobertJiang I may have read the question before the edit took place, I believe it had a square. In case of a cube, then I would go for Mickep's solution. Once you arrive at a denom of $cost-1$, through some trig steps you can still do that one with my high school trig, but using tan half angle formula is easier

Comment: @imranfat I have an integral which seems hard for me:
 $$\int\frac{1}{3+\cos^3{x}}\,\mathrm{d}x.$$
 If I use Weierstrass substitution I get $I=\int{\frac{(1+t^2)^2}{3(1+t^2)^3+(1-t^2)^3}dt} $ I was stuck here  I think I have already tried what you said but not easy

Comment: @RobertJiang Weierstrass is not the best solution here, because of that cube. Follow Mickep's method by first performing partial fraction decomposition

Comment: @imranfat you are right！ thx though it's still complex

Comment: @RobertJiang  Complex? Moahh, that's all relative ...:)

Comment: @imranfat You are right